# Program stops after input

Tags: python, api, input, openweathermap

I am using the openweather api to just get the current weather. I am able to get it to display the weather data using this code. (formatted api code out)

```
import requests

def current_weather():
    city_name = ('Houston')
    api_key = ('My api code')
    url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}').format(city_name, api_key)
    info = requests.get(url).json()
    print(info);

current_weather()
```

Result:

```
{
  'coord': {
    'lon': -95.3633,
    'lat': 29.7633
  },
  'weather': [
    {
      'id': 800,
      'main': 'Clear',
      'description': 'clear sky',
      'icon': '01d'
    }
  ],
  'base': 'stations',
  'main': {
    'temp': 295.42,
    'feels_like': 294.72,
    'temp_min': 294.14,
    'temp_max': 297.09,
    'pressure': 1024,
    'humidity': 39
  },
  'visibility': 10000,
  'wind': {
    'speed': 2.24,
    'deg': 66,
    'gust': 3.58
  },
  'clouds': {
    'all': 1
  },
  'dt': 1634495143,
  'sys': {
    'type': 2,
    'id': 2006306,
    'country': 'US',
    'sunrise': 1634473467,
    'sunset': 1634514521
  },
  'timezone': -18000,
  'id': 4699066,
  'name': 'Houston',
  'cod': 200
}
[Finished in 287ms]
```

But then for the city name I try getting it in the input and it just asks me which city I am in and stops the program.

```
def current_weather():
    city_name = input('What city are you in?: ')
    api_key = ('My api code')
    url = ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={}&appid={}').format(city_name, api_key)
    info = requests.get(url).json()
    print(info);

current_weather()
```

Result: What city are you in?: Paris

And nothing else.

Comment: That could probably be caused by `info` being `None`. What did you try to debug this? Are you familiar with setting `breakpoint()`s? This is a good use case for this. Write `response = requests.get(url)`, after the url assignment set a breakpoint and inspect it. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html for more information.

Comment: I did not know about the breakpoints. I am sort of new to this so that is good info. For whatever reason sublime was not outputting any info. I used pycharm and it worked. Not sure what the issue was.

Comment: you don't need the `()` around the strings BTW

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code myself and it seems like it should work. It appears you have a semicolon after `print(info)`, relatable mistake when returning to python after other languages.